# Where is video color vector scope in Apple Motion?

Tags: color-correction, motion, apple

Color vector scope views are very useful for grading color more objectively. I can find it easily in FCPX 10.4.6, but where can I find it in Motion? (currently using 5.4.3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a vectorscope in Apple Motion but in FCPX vectorscope comes in with the Color Grading tools. Apple Motion is not intended for this purpose, so I guess they did not require to add the vectorscope. I use version Apple Motion version 5.4.2

Comment: The same might be also applicable to Adobe After Effect, it doesn't have a vector scope either as far as I remember.